# How to copy <option> from one <select> to another?

Tags: jquery

I am using the two sided multi select found here http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/twosidedmultiselect.html and need to add the selected options in the right hand multiselect to another select list with JQuery. Has anyone had to do this before and knows a quick way of doing this?

`var selectedOptions = $("#myselect")[0].options;` will get the options but how to write these to the other select?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
var $options = $("#myselect > option").clone();

$('#secondSelectId').append($options);
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7aNRZ/)

Comment: Hi Two really nice solutions but what I am looking for is as the options are added to the dynamically created second select, ie the one that is created by the two sided multi select plugin they are also added to another select menu on the page thereby giving both the same content.

Comment: OK, got this working now with $().ready(function() {
  $('#primaryGroup').click(function() {
 return !$('#myselect option').appendTo('#primaryGroup');
 });

 $('#editgroup').click(function() {
 return !$('#primaryGroup option.moveme').appendTo('#myselect');
 });
 });

but.. the click event in chrome only works on second click, it's a known bug apparently, does anyone know a way round this?

Comment: and what would one do, if one would like to copy a specific number for items from the source list? For Example...if the source list has items 1-19 and we were to copy only item up-to selected item?

Comment: @asad copy only those, just change the selector.

Comment: @gdoron any hint on how? :)

Comment: working fiddle if anyone can help please: http://jsfiddle.net/asadmalik/7aNRZ/721/

Answer (score 16):

```
<select multiple="true" class="multiselect1" name="myselecttsms1">
    <option value="1" rel="0" title="One">One</option>
    <option value="2" rel="1" title="Two">Two</option>            
    <option value="4" rel="3" title="Four">Four</option>
    <option value="5" rel="4" title="Five">Five</option>
    <option value="6" rel="5" title="Six">Six</option>
</select>

<select multiple="true" class="multiselect2" name="myselecttsms2" size="6">

</select>

<button class="add">Add</button>
<button class="addAll">Add All</button>
<button class="remove">Remove</button>
<button class="removeAll">Remove All</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.add').on('click', function() {
    var options = $('select.multiselect1 option:selected').sort().clone();
    $('select.multiselect2').append(options);
});
$('.addAll').on('click', function() {
    var options = $('select.multiselect1 option').sort().clone();
    $('select.multiselect2').append(options);
});
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
    $('select.multiselect2 option:selected').remove();
});
$('.removeAll').on('click', function() {
    $('select.multiselect2').empty();
});
```

**[Sample Workout](http://jsfiddle.net/dm85y/1/)**

Comment: nice. I guess we can tweak it a little bit so that an option is added to right side only once.

Answer (score 11):

There is an even easier way to do this:

```
var options = $("#myOldSelect").html();
$('#myNewSelect').html(options);
```

This is really handy if you want to add the new Select to the DOM with the copied options already included:

```
var options = $("#myOldSelect").html();
$("#domLocation").append("<select id='myNewSelect'>" + options + "</select");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#cloneBtn').click(function() {
    var $options = $("#myselect > option").clone();
    $('#second').empty();
    $('#second').append($options);
    $('#second').val($('#myselect').val());
});
```

This is used to copy the value and the innerHTML.
   Its better to copy the key, value and the OPTIONS.i.e. the selected value and the options.

Comment: nice answer. It keeps select on the new select box.

Comment: This is my favorite answer. Thank you. By the way, I have a question for you. Why do you need the code line: var $options = $("#myselect > option").clone(); ?