# copy data from one Html.listboxfor to other listbox in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery-ui, model-view-controller, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two `Html.ListBoxFor` called `A` & `B`.

1) `A` has data populated from DB & `B` is empty.

2) I want a functionality like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dm85y/1/) where items from list `A` are placed into list `B`.

```
$('.add').on('click', function() {
    var options = $('select.multiselect1 option:selected').sort().clone();
    $('select.multiselect2').append(options);
});
$('.addAll').on('click', function() {
    var options = $('select.multiselect1 option').sort().clone();
    $('select.multiselect2').append(options);
});
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
    $('select.multiselect2 option:selected').remove();
});
$('.removeAll').on('click', function() {
    $('select.multiselect2').empty();
});
```

3) I tried this with asp.net mvc, but I was unable to fetch the selected items in model & controller.

4) I want a way by which we can perform this in asp.net mvc. If there can be some way in mvc then I would be able to store that data in SQL DB

5) Its jquery sibling is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781500/how-to-copy-option-from-one-select-to-another)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What did you try with MVC? The code should be pretty similar.

Comment: @RudiVisser please see this paste http://pastebin.com/mb2TdLG0

Comment: What is the type in the model? It might be worth accepting `int[]` for `B` and recreating your database entities in the controller.

Comment: I tried List<team> , int[] , List<SelectListItem> , string [] , but still not able to fetch listbox values in controller . I found a strange thing after I tried form collection , but the property of listbox was not present in form collection . The rest of all UI controls were there . What can be the reason ?

Comment: I found 1 thing that if I select all items in listbox & click submit , then I get all the selected items in form collection , but not in model . Still I am getting error "**The value '3,5,7' is invalid**". These are the ids of selected items . Don't know what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.

Blockquote

Html file

```
Fruits:
        <select multiple="multiple" id="a">
            <option value="1">Apple</option>
            <option value="2">Orange</option>
            <option value="3">Banana</option>
        </select>

        <input type="button" id="add" value="Add"/>
         <input type="button" id="addall" value="Add all"/>
        <select multiple="multiple" id="b">

        </select>
```

Javascript File

```
$("#add").bind("click", function () {
        addOption(false);

 });

$("#addall").bind("click", function () {
    addOption(true);

});

function addOption(isAll){
    var option = $("#a option");
    if (!isAll) {
       option = $("#a option:selected");
    } else {
       $("#b").html("");
    }

    $(option).each(function () {
       var val = $(this).val();
       var text = $(this).text();
       $("#b").append($(this)[0].outerHTML);
       $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: Nope pal , my situation acts with asp.net mvc rather than  jquery , I have to store the values in database with state management .