# How to bind combo box values in multiple combo boxes using loop

Tags: jquery

Working and stuck with jquery performance.

I have a combo box loaded completely.. with id name ""combo""

Now, I want this combo box values in my 3 different combo boxes ...

All my combo boxes having same id name with number

Eg 
Combo1
Combo2
Combo3

Now in my callback method I am using for loop

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    $('#Combo' + (i+1)).append($('#combo').html());
}
```

It is not binding any of my combo boxes...
But when I debug from developer tools in chrome  and slowly iterate this with debugger then it works.

I'm not getting whats happening

Comment: document ready handler

Comment: `It is not binding any of my combo boxes...`  Please elaborate on what you mean by this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy <option> from one <select> to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781500/how-to-copy-option-from-one-select-to-another)

Comment: Can you share your HTML as well?

Comment: I have one combo box loaded completely....Now  I want my other combo boxes should contains same values... So I am appending this to all my other combo boxes....Hence in loop